# SQLAlchemy: Hybrid Value Object, Query Tuple Results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I am trying to follow the examples from the documentation on building [custom comparators](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#hybrid-value-objects) using hybrid value objects,

```
class CaseInsensitiveWord(Comparator):
    "Hybrid value representing a lower case representation of a word."

    def __init__(self, word):
        if isinstance(word, basestring):
            self.word = word.lower()
        elif isinstance(word, CaseInsensitiveWord):
            self.word = word.word
        else:
            self.word = func.lower(word)

    def operate(self, op, other):
        if not isinstance(other, CaseInsensitiveWord):
            other = CaseInsensitiveWord(other)
        return op(self.word, other.word)

    def __clause_element__(self):
        return self.word

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word

    key = 'word'
    "Label to apply to Query tuple results"
```

I don't understand, however, why this was added to the end of the class definition:

```
key = 'word'
"Label to apply to Query tuple results"
```

What is this for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not a fully baked Python feature, a convention is to comment attributes in the same way as functions and methods, i.e. by placing a string below the attribute.    Comments like the above are picked up by tools like Sphinx.    You can see examples of these docstrings getting generated in places like http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.class_manager.

edit: oh why it has an actual ".key".  When you say:

```
for row in session.query(MyClass.mycustomthing, MyClass.myothercustomthing):
   print row.word, row.someotherword
```

the "word" and "someotherword" tuple keys are the value of ".key" on each comparator.  if you were to call label() on it, that would change it to something else.  I don't know that it's strictly necessary to be there at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also curious, what is the point of the attribute itself? Key?